# How can I get all the rows of ag-grid?

Tags: angular5, ag-grid

ag-grid provides a way to get selected rows using `api.getSelectedRows()` function. And provides a way to set all rows using `api.setRowData([])` function.
I'm looking for something `getAllRows()` to return all the rows in the grid. I know there is a way to loop through all the rows using `api.forEachNode()` etc.
Is there any way I can get the entire array of rows?

Answer (score 50):

I don't think there is such a method but you can make your own:

```
getAllRows() {
  let rowData = [];
  this.gridApi.forEachNode(node => rowData.push(node.data));
  return rowData;
}
```

Comment: I am doing the same for now but, was wondering if ag-grip provides any inbuilt function for the same. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: I have tried to find one so I'm at least 90% sure there is no such thing.
The closest one I found is if you do api.getModel() that returns a InMemoryRowModel that has the property rowsToDisplay.

Comment: OP already tried 'api.forEachNode()' (as mentioned in original question) and is expecting an inbuilt function/property which can return rows/count in grid

Comment: From the video link below, the array always keep updated and rendered to the DOM.
Do not need to retrieve row data.
https://youtu.be/_V5qFr62uhY

Comment: How do you do this in React Hook (without using "this")?

Comment: I don't think the above code will work if you have row groups.

Answer (score 15):

you are looking for `getRenderedNodes`

```
gridOptions.api.getRenderedNodes()
```

Note: this will only retrieve the *rendered* rows. If you use row virtualization, meaning only the rows in the viewport will be in the DOM, only those will be returned. As per the functions docs:

> Retrieve rendered nodes. Due to virtualisation this will contain only the current visible rows and those in the buffer.

Comment: not sure if there's a better answer out there, but this is the best answer on this thread by a country mile.  thx.

Comment: This is excellent and the best answer to the question above. Thanks for sharing your knowlegde with us!

Comment: This doesn't work if you have a tree-grid displaying the same node at multiple locations of the tree.

Comment: gridOptions.api.getRenderedNodes().map(x=>x.data)

Answer (score 7):

Ag-grid doesn't provide any method to do that. You can check it here [Accessing Data Ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-accessing-data/) and here [Grid Api](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/).

I guest the reason is because you can do it through a loop, as you mentioned before.

```js
    let items: Array<rows> = [];
    this.gridApi.forEachNode(function(node) { 
        items.push(node.data);
    });
```

Or if the source of your ag-grid is linked through angular there is no need to loop over the grid (assuming that the data grid has not pending changes)

Answer (score 7):

I think this is the simplest answer.

let {rowsToDisplay} = params.api.getModel();

Answer (score 4):

**Update 2023-05-27:** As comments on this answer have pointed out, the answer I gave originally is incorrect, especially for the latest version of AG Grid which doesn't even have `gridOptionsWrapper`.

Looping through `api.forEachNode()` and building a data array manually seems to be the best option.

---

This is how I get the rowData from the grid API:

```
api.getModel().gridOptionsWrapper.gridOptions.rowData
```

Lots of methods include `gridOptionsWrapper` in their return object, so you don't necessarily have to use `getModel()`.

Comment: In this case, you will get an initial value of rowData, but not an updated, for example, if some row was removed.

Comment: The GridOptionsWrapper API [was removed](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/commit/53d6dd2135b898b07c2eb822e22b6ac3676428e6) for v29 in scope of the private issue *AG-7603 Delete GridOptionsWrapper*

Answer (score 1):

```
  **`Try This:`**
```

All the selected nodes can b edisplayed here

```
  const rowsToDisplay = api?.getRenderedNodes()?.map(node => node?.data)
```

For SSR

```
  const { selectAll = false, toggledNodes = [] } = params.api?.getServerSideSelectionState() || {};
```

Comment: You can improve your answer by explaining why

Answer (score 0):

It gives a list of all rows, even if you filter by any columns.

```
getAllRows() {
  let allRows = [];
  this.gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilter((rowNode) => allRows.push(rowNode));
  return allRows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you are just looking for data then try

```
this.gridOptions.rowData
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code gives you all rows whether they rendered or not without looping:

```
var allRows = gridApi.rowModel.rowsToDisplay;
```

Answer (score -1):

I was wondering the same thing and found it annoying that you cannot simply get all rows.  In my case I needed to flip a flag on all rows, where the indicator is set outside the component containing the grid, so I did the following.  This is in TypeScript for a React app.

```
  gridApi!.selectAll();
  const rows = gridApi!.getSelectedRows();

  rows.forEach(row => {
    row.coverageAction = this.props.isIndicatorChecked;
  });

  gridApi!.setRowData(rows);
```